# Oracle: execute a Job dbms_scheduler

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, job-scheduling, dbms-scheduler

I Want to execute a Scheduler in Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
I have this package:

```
create or replace PACKAGE  "S_IN_TDK" is


procedure parseMsg;

end;
```

and this job

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name         =>  'parseMsg',
   program_name     =>  'S_IN_TDK.parseMsg',
   repeat_interval  =>  'FREQ=SECONDLY;INTERVAL=10',
   --job_style        => 'LIGHTWEIGHT',
   comments         => 'Job that polls device n2 every 10 seconds');
END;
```

but when I run the job I got this error:

```
Fallo al procesar el comando SQL
- ORA-27476: "S_IN_TDK.PARSEMSG" does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 185
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 486
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

I also tried

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name         =>  'parseMsg',
   job_action       =>  'begin S_IN_TDK.parseMsg; end;',
   repeat_interval  =>  'FREQ=SECONDLY;INTERVAL=10',
   --job_style        => 'LIGHTWEIGHT',
   comments         => 'Job that polls device n2 every 10 seconds');
END;
```

but then I got this error:

```
 Informe de error -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CREATE_JOB'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72300) has three required parameters: `job_name`, `job_type`, and `job_action`.  Add `job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',` and also add `enabled => true,` to make the job run immediately.

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name         =>  'parseMsg',
   job_type         =>  'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action       =>  'begin S_IN_TDK.parseMsg; end;',
   repeat_interval  =>  'FREQ=SECONDLY;INTERVAL=10',
   --job_style        => 'LIGHTWEIGHT',
   enabled          =>  true,
   comments         => 'Job that polls device n2 every 10 seconds');
END;
/
```

Use this query to check the job status:

```
select *
from dba_scheduler_job_run_details
where job_name = 'PARSEMSG'
order by log_date desc;
```

Answer (score 3):

Parameter `program_name` expects the name of a scheduler `PROGRAM` object.  If you want to run an inline program then do use `job_action` parameter instead:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name         =>  'parseMsg',
   job_action       =>  'begin S_IN_TDK.parseMsg; end;',
   repeat_interval  =>  'FREQ=SECONDLY;INTERVAL=10',
   --job_style        => 'LIGHTWEIGHT',
   comments         => 'Job that polls device n2 every 10 seconds');
END;
```

Note that `job_action` expects a complete PL/SQL block as input.